# Button image color different on iPhone X as compared to older iPhones

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am adding an image to a UIButton:

```
setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "IconCamera"), for: .normal)
```

The image is appearing different on iPhone X as compared to, iPhone 5s, iPhone 6 and iPhone 7 plus.

[image: iPhone 6 screenshot]

iPhone 6 screenshot.

[image]

iPhone X screenshot.

[image]

Image added in the asset.
This the @3x image of the 3 images I have added. Also, the image is in PNG.
Tried putting in vector image in PDF format. Same result.

Can anyone tell, why this difference is there?

Answer (score -1):

May be you use different images (seems like to you use images with different contrast).
Try to use single scale images for experiment.

Comment: I did. Did not work. Tried using vector image as well, did not work.